# How do I create websites on remote servers using appcmd?

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, appcmd

I have used appcmd to create websites on my local computer. There doesn't appear to be a server parameter which means that i have to remote desktop on to each machine that i'm deploying to and run the appcmd command.

Also, can i use appcmd to deploy to IIS 6.0? If not, how do i deploy to remote IIS 6.0 web servers? I've tried the iisweb.vbs but i can't get it to run on my windows 7 computer because it can#t find the Microsoft.cmdlib. I have tired registering this file but it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching of the internet i could not find an existing tool that needs to do what i need it to do. So in the end i had to create my own utility application that creates websites using WMI.

Answer (score 2):

Using psexec.exe from sysinternals has worked for me to run appcmd on the IIS7 host from my administration host.

Answer (score 0):

you can run a web service on the target machine, the web service should have the privileges
to add websites to the iis server (done by using System.DirectoryServices

Comment: I think there are security issues with your proposed solution.