# How to configure IIS remotely using powershell?

Tags: iis, powershell, batch-file, remote-access

I am trying to write a simple script that lets you remotely add an app pool, site, and app to IIS using powershell.

I figured out how to do this using APPCMD with a .bat on the local machine, but I need to do this remotely.

My bat file works and contains:

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD add apppool /name:"WCF Integrated 4.0" /managedRuntimeVersion:"v4.0" /managedPipelineMode:Integrated /processModel.identityType:"NetworkService" /enable32BitAppOnWin64:True

%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD add site /name:"WCF Site" /bindings:"http/*:88:" /physicalPath:"D:\wcf"

%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD add app /site.name:"WCF Site" /path:/Service/Host /physicalPath:"D:\wcf\Service"

%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD set app /app.name:"WCF Site/Service/Host" /applicationPool:"WCF Integrated 4.0"
```

Comment: any full source code sample with final solution? thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create websites on remote servers using appcmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034102/how-do-i-create-websites-on-remote-servers-using-appcmd)

Answer (score 5):

You didn't specify which version of IIS. If you are on 7.x, you can use the web [administration module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/433/powershell-snap-in-creating-web-sites-web-applications-virtual-directories-and-application-pools/). Your script would resemble this:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName '<ComputerName>'

    $block = { 
        import-module 'webAdministration' 

            # Call IIS cmdlets here for adding app pools, creating web site and so on
    } 

Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock $block
```